# Find the expression for the following coefficient

Tags: combinatorics

I've asked a similar question to this, but this one is more complicated and I'm unsure of my solution.

I need to find an expression for the nth coefficient in the following

$$(1+3x)^{-5m}(1-2x^2)^7$$

I used the binomial theorem to get the following

$$[x^{n}]\sum\limits_{k=0}^{5m} {k+5m-1 \choose 5m-1}(-3)^kx^k \sum\limits_{j=0}^{7} {7 \choose j}2^kx^{2k}$$

and simplified it to be

$$[x^{n}]\sum\limits_{k=0}^{5m}\sum\limits_{j=0}^{7} {k+5m-1 \choose 5m-1}(-3)^k  {7 \choose j}2^kx^{3k}$$

let n=3k so k=n/3 which gives the following for the expression for the nth coefficient

$$[x^{n}]=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{7} {n/3+5m-1 \choose 5m-1}(-3)^{n/3}  {7 \choose j}2^{n/3}$$

Please let me know if I've done anything wrong! Thanks!

Comment: Is $m$ negative ?

Comment: hmm I'm not sure, the problem doesn't specify. Would it make dramatic changes if it could be?

Comment: I'm told I can assume the value of m to be positive